# Are all automorphisms of Lin(V) given by similarity transforms?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $V$ be a vector space with dimension greater than 1 over the field $F$ and $Sim = \{(f\in \operatorname{Lin}(V))\mapsto gf(g^{-1}) : g\in \operatorname{GL}(V)\}$, ie $Sim$ is the set of all similarity transforms on $\operatorname{Lin}(V)$.  Let $Aut$ be the set of all automorphisms of the $F$-algebra $\operatorname{Lin}(V)$.

What is $Aut\setminus Sim$?  In particular, is it empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M$ denote the $F$-algebra $\hom(V, V)$. An $F$-algebra homomorphism $M \to \hom(V, V)$ is tantamount to an $M$-module structure on $V$ in the category of $F$-vector spaces. But the category of $M$-modules is equivalent to $Vect_F$ (there is a Morita equivalence between the categories given by the functor $- \otimes_F V: Vect_F \to Mod_M$). That is to say, every $M$-module is isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of $V$, and in particular, any module structure on $V$ is isomorphic to the standard $M$-module structure on $V$.

So, if $\mu': M \otimes_F V \to V$ is any module structure, and $\mu: M \otimes_F V \to V$ denotes the standard structure, there is an isomorphism $g: V \to V$ such that $g \circ \mu' = \mu \circ (M \otimes_F g)$. Putting all this together, any $F$-algebra *homomorphism* $M \to \hom(V, V)$ is obtained by conjugating the standard homomorphism (the identity) by an isomorphism $g: V \to V$.

Edit: If this proof seems too categorical, there is a proof in slightly alternative language given on page 401 of Bilinear algebra: An Introduction to the algebraic theory of quadratic forms by Szymiczek (Google books [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=CcM8_iiGPxAC&pg=PA401&lpg=PA401&dq=automorphisms+of+a+matrix+algebra&source=bl&ots=Ba5Y2F3AbT&sig=qX8ef4eQVkLoFN-_5CtHGX4s8h8&hl=en&ei=7hm5TJyVOs6s8AauyfH-Dg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=7&ved=0CDQQ6AEwBjgK#v=onepage&q=automorphisms%20of%20a%20matrix%20algebra&f=false).

Comment: Am I missing a reason for you writing $M \to \hom(V, V)$ instead of $M \to M$?

Comment: I wrote it that way in remembrance of the canonical bijection between linear maps $M \to \hom_F(V, V)$ and linear maps $M \otimes_F V \to V$, and (by specializing) between algebra maps and module structures. I was trying to segue from a question about algebras to a module-theoretic question. 


Comment: Okay, I'm lost in the category theory, but how could we possibly get the zero homomorphism by conjugating the identity with an isomorphism?

Comment: That's not an algebra homomorphism -- it doesn't preserve the identity. 

Comment: I have updated my answer to point you to a slightly different proof. 

Comment: Thanks.  (I would have accepted it even before you added that, it just took me a while to give up trying to comment first since the site wouldn't let me.)

Comment: It surprises me that this shows that every algebra endomorphism of $End(V)$ is actually an automorphism.

Comment: I am confused: are you assuming that $V$ is finite-dimensional?

Comment: I was. If OP meant to consider infinite-dimensional $V$ as well (and it seems there's no indication he doesn't), then I'd have to rethink the problem. The Morita business I had in mind does assume finite-dimensionality. 

Answer (score 1):

If $V$ is finite-dimensional, this fact is a simple consequence of [Skolem-Noether Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem-Noether_theorem)

Comment: which, of course, links to an error page.

Comment: Of course, you know, this means war!

Comment: Bugs was won :-)